# Remove substrings that vary in value in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column in Oracle which can contain up to 5 separate values, each separated by a `'|'`. Any of the values can be present or missing. Here are come examples of how the data might look:

```
100-1
10-3|25-1|120/240
15-1|15-3|15-2|120/208
15-1|15-3|15-2|120/208|STA-2
112-123|120/208|STA-3
```

The values are arbitrary except for the order. The numerical values separated by dashes always come first. There can be 1 to 3 of these values present. The numerical values separated by a slash (if it is present) is next. The string, 'STA', and a numerical value separated by a dash is always last, if it is present.

What I would like to do is reformat this column to only ever include the first three possible values, those being the three numerical values separated by dashes. Afterwards, I want to replace 2nd numeric in each value (the numeric after the dash) using the following pattern:

```
1 = A
2 = B
3 = C
```

I would also like to remove the dash afterwards, but not the `'|'` that separates the values unless there is a trailing `'|'`.

To give you an idea, here's how the values at the beginning of the post would look after the reformatting:

```
100A
10C|25A
15A|15C|15B
15A|15C|15B
112ABC
```

I'm thinking this can be done with regex expressions but it's got me a little confused. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: So the part `120/208|STA-2` will be eliminated too ?

Comment: That is correct. Only the first three possible values are important.

Comment: By regex [`\d+(-\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/iU1gH4/1) you can match that part but replacement is pretty challenging and here we will need some programming or might be some functionality in Oracle that am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to solve this problem I will solve it in following ways.

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'\|\d+\/\d+(\|STA-\d+)?',''),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'(\d+)-(1)([^\d])','\1A\3'),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'(\d+)-(2)([^\d])','\1B\3'),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'(\d+)-(3)([^\d])','\1C\3'),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'(\d+)-(123)([^\d])','\1ABC')
FROM table;
```

**Explanation:** Let us break down each `REGEXP_REPLACE` statement one by one.

1. `REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'\|\d+\/\d+(\|STA-\d+)?','')`
    
   This will replace the end part like `120/208|STA-2` with empty string so that further processing is easy.
2. Finding match was easy but replacing `A` for `1`, `B` for `2` and `C` for `3` was not possible ( as per my knowledge ) So I did those matching and replacements separately.

   In each regex from second statement `(\d+)-(yourNumber)([^\d])` first group is number before `-` then `yourNumber` is either `1`,`2`,`3` or `123` followed by `|`.

   So the replacement will be according to `yourNumber`.

<kbd>[All demos here from version 1 to 5.](https://regex101.com/r/sB9lG1/1)</kbd>

**Note:-** I have just done replacement for combination of `yourNUmber` for those present in question. You can do likewise for other combinations too.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in one line, but you can write simple function to do that

```
SELECT str, REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(\|\d+\/\d+)?(\|STA-\d+)?','') cut
, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(\|\d+\/\d+)?(\|STA-\d+)?',''), '(\-)([1,2]*)(3)([1,2]*)', '\1\2C\4') rep3toC
, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(\|\d+\/\d+)?(\|STA-\d+)?',''), '(\-)([1,2]*)(3)([1,2]*)', '\1\2C\4'), '(\-)([1,C]*)(2)([1,C]*)', '\1\2B\4') rep2toB
, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(\|\d+\/\d+)?(\|STA-\d+)?',''), '(\-)([1,2]*)(3)([1,2]*)', '\1\2C\4'), '(\-)([1,C]*)(2)([1,C]*)', '\1\2B\4'), '(\-)([B,C]*)(1)([B,C]*)', '\1\2A\4') rep1toA
, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(\|\d+\/\d+)?(\|STA-\d+)?',''), '(\-)([1,2]*)(3)([1,2]*)', '\1\2C\4'), '(\-)([1,C]*)(2)([1,C]*)', '\1\2B\4'), '(\-)([B,C]*)(1)([B,C]*)', '\1\2A\4'), '-', '') "rep-"
FROM (
SELECT '100-1' str FROM dual UNION 
SELECT '10-3|25-1|120/240' str FROM dual UNION 
SELECT '15-1|15-3|15-2|120/208' str FROM dual UNION 
SELECT '15-1|15-3|15-2|120/208|STA-2' str FROM dual UNION 
SELECT '112-123|120/208|STA-3' FROM dual     
) tab
```